# Java Collection Interface addAll() method signature

Tags: java, generics, collections

What difference would it make if Java Collection Interface has addAll method signature like this

```
 <T extends E> boolean addAll(Collection<T> c);
```

rather than 
`boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c);`?

Thanks

-Abidi

Comment: This doesn't compile here. The following does however: <T extends E> boolean addAll(Collection<T> c);

Comment: My bad Puce, going to edit it. My question remains there though. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take this test interface:

```
public interface DumbTestInterface<E> {

    <T extends E> boolean addAll1(Collection<T> c);

    boolean addAll2(Collection<? extends E> c);

}
```

Here's the byte code:

```
// Compiled from DumbTestInterface.java (version 1.6 : 50.0, no super bit)
// Signature: <E:Ljava/lang/Object;>Ljava/lang/Object;
public abstract interface rumba.dumba.DumbTestInterface {

  // Method descriptor #6 (Ljava/util/Collection;)Z
  // Signature: <T:TE;>(Ljava/util/Collection<TT;>;)Z
  public abstract boolean addAll1(java.util.Collection arg0);

  // Method descriptor #6 (Ljava/util/Collection;)Z
  // Signature: (Ljava/util/Collection<+TE;>;)Z
  public abstract boolean addAll2(java.util.Collection arg0);
}
```

As you can see there's no difference in the resulting byte code (apart from the generated debug code). So if the two versions are equivalent, you might as well stick with the version that's easier to understand.

Answer (score 4):

In this case, having `<?>` or `<T>` is equivalent for users of `addAll`.

I think that the former notation was used for clarity, because using `<T>` makes the signature of `addAll` more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

The thing is, the `T` in `<T extends E> boolean addAll(Collection<T> c)` is completely unnecessary, because `addAll` *doesn't care* what specific subtype of `E` the collection it's given contains. All it cares is that the collection it's given contains *some subtype* of `E`, which is exactly what `Collection<? extends E>` means.

You shouldn't introduce unnecessary generic types to a method.

Answer (score 0):

If you used an explicit class T, then you could not pass a wildcarded collection to the method, which is something that you may want to do and should be able to.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, when the type variable `T` is only going to be used in one place somewhere in the types of the parameters, you can safely change it to `?`.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think that would compile. A method cannot have two return types (`<T>` and `boolean`) at the same time.

Comment: `<T>` is not a return type. It's a generic type.